Piece-wise synchronization of tracks
I have two independently recorded tracks with the same content that I'd like to synchronize. The problem is, long chunks of silence were independently cut out of both tracks, so even if I align the beginning, the tracks will get out of sync after a while.
I would like to avoid manually fiddling with cursors set to peaks and removing/inserting extra silence time to get tracks aligned. Ideally, I'd like to find an automated solution to:

Split track 1 into short pieces on silence blocks
Match these pieces with track 2, keeping pieces strictly in order
Reassemble pieces back in a new version of track 1, now synchronized with track 2.

If that's not easily feasible, I would settle for a semi-automated solution:

Split both tracks in fixed-size chunks longer than the expected desync time (e.g. 10 seconds)
Do a cross-correlation between corresponding chunks of track 1 and track 2 to estimate the delay
Plot the delay vs. time
Manually insert/delete silence in track 1 around timestamps where the delay increases/decreases.

I'm pretty sure both strategies are feasible in MATLAB/Octave with signal-processing toolbox. Of course, it would still be a lot of work to implement a usable interface, so I'd rather do this with an actual audio editor.
I'm currently using Audacity for manual editing, so a solution involving Audacity features and plugins would save me from learning a new tool, but I'm open to other solutions as well, if they save time in the end.

So what you're looking for is basically a sample aligner. The only studio-plugin I can think of that would do that sort of thing is a

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
